# How to use an image to identify it in another in python?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, automation, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I am working on a gui automation project. I have a screenshot of an object. IF THE OBJECT IS IN ANOTHER IMAGE THE CODE HAVE TO DO ANY ACTION. I am a beginner and I don't know about this kinda stuff. PLEASE HELP ME. THANKS FOR THOSE HELPS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Have you tried to research on the topic? If you haven't, please do research on the topic. If you have, then attach the shortened version of your code you have done so far. And, what exactly is the error? And, what do you mean by 'DO ANY ACTION'?

Comment: And refer to this [link](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#:~:text=PyAutoGUI%20can%20take%20screenshots%2C%20save,which%20is%20installed%20with%20PyAutoGUI.)